# Difference between "with" and "to"

Tags: prepositions, difference

"With" and "to" are very important prepositions in the English language. I know the usage of both prepositions but some points I become stuck with when should I use which preposition.

For example:

> He is kind/good/generous to me.
> He is kind/good/generous with me.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

'to' is directed towards only one person, whereas, 'with' includes both people.
Example: John was talking to Smith.
John was speaking with Smith.
In the first sentence, only John is speaking.
In the second sentence, a conversation of two people is implied.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work when talking about two people who are engaged or married.  We don't say "A is engaged/married with B"  We say "A is engaged/married TO B".